# spring boot config client crypto dependencies?

Tags: spring-boot, encryption, bouncycastle

I am using spring boot v 2.0.6.RELEASE and

```
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    <spring.cloud.client.version>2.0.2.RELEASE</spring.cloud.client.version>
```

and

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</dependencyManagement>
```

also

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.cloud.client.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

My app runs locally but junit fails with this

Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor]: Factory method 'textEncryptor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/util/io/pem/PemObjectGenerator

I thought spring boot is supposed to bring the dependencies of crypto it needs

what am I doing wrong?

Edit 1:

The class is part of bouncycastle
it exists in config server but not in client

```
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.56:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.56:compile
```

Comment: First check which jar the missing class belongs then Look at maven dependency hierarchy and see why the dependency is not available at test scope.

Comment: its bouncycastle, exists in server but not client

Comment: If you need it in test scope try explicitly adding its dependency, if not needed exclude it from test scope.

Comment: ok but should it be not there in cloud client by default? I would hate hard coding the versions

Answer (score 0):

It is kinda related to this

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/84

If you have a client that needs to decrypt passwords

Add spring-cloud-starter as dependency

I added

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.cloud.client.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```